# How do I get the b-complement of 193 for b = 5?

Tags: binary, complement, basis

So I am supposed to find the b-complement for 193 given that b = 5 and the number of digits allowed is n = 6.

Now I think I am a bit confused regarding the b-complement in general.

Is it that whenever b is odd, just like in the case we have here, you are supposed to subtract 1 from the base and calculate the complement with the result?

If that's the case, you would calculate the 4-complement of 193, right?
But do I then also subtract the then found out number from 444444 or still 555555?

Comment: What is the b-complement?

Comment: From what I understood it's similar to the 2's complement only it is not to the basis 2 but to what ever basis b is given